# Python: how to subset from a large dataframe based upon a maximum value in a column and nrows before and nrows after including the self

Tags: python, pandas, subset

Suppose:

```
df['Column_Name'].max() # is the maximum value in a particular column in a dataframe
```

Then, you want to select 10 rows before the row that has maximum value in a particular column and 10 rows after that row (i.e. 10 + 1 + 10 = 21 rows total), then, how can it be done in Python?

Comment: Are you using Pandas? Your use of the word "dataframe" seems to indicate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to get the index of the row that has the maximum value. Assuming you're using Pandas, this would be done by using `idxmax()`.

```
>>> from pandas import DataFrame
>>> data = [{'a':x} for x in range(40)]
>>> from random import shuffle
>>> shuffle(data)
>>> df = DataFrame(data)
>>> index_of_max_value = df['a'].idxmax()
>>> df['a'][max(0,index_of_max_value-10):min(len(df['a']), index_of_max_value+11)]
19    16
20    36
21     8
22    20
23    14
24    31
25     6
26    18
27    17
28    23
29    39
30     5
31    25
32     4
33    12
34    35
35    26
36     0
37    27
38    21
39    30
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an addition to @2rs2ts solution to account for your max value being near the beginning or end of your series or dataframe.

```
df['a'][max(0,index_of_max_value-10):min(len(df['a']), index_of_max_value+11)]
```